# many failed attempts to login although root login is disabled

Tags: centos, ssh, root, authentication

I am trying to disable root login. I set `PermitRootLogin no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

When I run ssh `root@IP`, I get `Permission denied, please try again.` which is correct.

When I login into root using `su -` command from another user, I still see XXXXX number of failed login attempts.

Is this normal or did I forgot about something?

I am running CentOS 7.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have disabled root logins and you have no successful login attempts. Everything looks right. Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: nono, when I use su - to login to root rom another user I see a wast amount of failed login attempts.

Comment: So? You're probably hit by automatic scans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this normal or did I forgot about something? I am running centos 7.

Yes, it is normal and expected behavior. Failed attempts are always logged and if the `root` is not allowed to login, every attempt though ssh fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the root account with `sudo passwd -l root`. Editing the sshd_config file affects ssh logins only. This disables `su -` as well since the password is not known by anyone.

from `man passwd`:

> -l, --lock
>              Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the
>              beginning of the password).
>
> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
> Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.

Comment: Thanks, but the main goal was to disable ssh root login, since that is what attackers are doing. To my best understanding, ssh root login is disabled in my case?